# How do I get all articles about people from Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

What would be the easiest way to get all articles about people from Wikipedia? I know I can download a dump of all the pages, but then how do I filter those and get only the ones about people? I need as many as I can get (preferably more than a million) so using any sort of API is probably not an option.

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking for, aside from over a million Wikipedia articles about people (which isn't a suitable topic for SO).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you asking for advice on how to implement a web spider?

Comment: No, I don't think spidering is appropriate in this case. It's possible to download a dump file of wikipedia. The question is how to filter the dump file XML and get only the pages which are about people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since articles about people usually contain the Persondata template, you can just search for all articles that contain Persondata.  You can find a sample API query for doing just that here:

[Does the Wikipedia API support searches for a specific template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043003/does-the-wikipedia-api-support-searches-for-a-specific-template)

Answer (score 8):

As of 2014 you have another option: Query [WikiData](https://www.wikidata.org) for all entities where the property [`instance of` (P31)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property%3aP31) has the value [`human` (Q5)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5).

Full list of humans: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Q5

From that list, filter out any thing that doesn't have a [`sex or gender` (P21)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property%3aP21), to get rid of pages like “scientist”

This way, you don't need to keep track of what templates are used for people in each and every different language edition (there are [285](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias)) of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to roll out on your own, basically what you need is to focus is on the "**infobox** data" in the XML dump.

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/infobox2rdf/

Or you can also checkout the http://www.freebase.com or http://dbpedia.org