# MediaWiki API Search titles of pages with specific template

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is there a way to query MediaWiki / Wikipedia for pages by title **and** template?

For example I would like to know if there is a page that has the title "Some Person" and contains the "Template:Persondata".

I know how to query by title:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Some%20Person&format=xml&redirects

And thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043003/does-the-wikipedia-api-support-searches-for-a-specific-template) I know how to search for all pages that use a certain template:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Persondata&format=xml'

But I can't figure out how to combine those two questions, to reduce my requests against the api.

Comment: I think you want a Wikidata query instead, checking whether the entity with that name has [P31:5] (instance of: human).

Answer (score 0):

No not directly through one API-request. Either you do an intersect yourself or you use this tool http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php which can do what you want (and much more).