# Wikipedia Api Extensions with Php

Tags: php, curl, wikipedia

Iam using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956331/how-to-get-results-from-the-wikipedia-api-with-php) Wikipedia-Php Request Methode.
Now, i will get back only people, and not companys or a kind of that.
My actualy url is like this:

```
$url = 'http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles='.$q.'&prop=revisions&rvprop=content';
```

i had searched in the wikipedia api-description, but i don't have find any help that will answer my question.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get all articles about people from Wikipedia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017166/how-do-i-get-all-articles-about-people-from-wikipedia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no certain way to chose only articles about people. You either try to traverse your way through the sub categories from [Kategorie:Person](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Person), but that will give you **a lot** of false positives, or you can look for pages containing any of the templates that are common on pages about persons (this will vary a lot, depending on what WP edition you are talking about).

I would, however, recommend you to have a look at WikiData or DBPedia, where you can get structured data from Wikipedia. Some hints are here: [How do I get all articles about people from Wikipedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017166/how-do-i-get-all-articles-about-people-from-wikipedia/23041989#23041989)